# fstab and systemd automount overlay

Tags: systemd, fstab, mkdir

On an embedded device based on Yocto Linux my rootfs is RO, while I have an additional partition for RW data. Now I want to automount at boot an overlay onto /etc stored on a different partition. Here is my fstab:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p6 /data_local ext4 defaults,sync,noexec,rw 0 2
[...]
overlay /etc overlay defaults,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data_local/overlayfs/upper/etc,workdir=/data_local/overlayfs/workdir,X-mount.mkdir,x-systemd.requires=/data_local,x-systemd.before=local-fs.target,x-systemd.before=systemd-networkd 0 0
```

However, this fails because the upperdir and workdir directories are missing on first boot. How can I let fstab or systemd.mount automatically create these directories?

Comment: I ended up using the overlayfs-etc.bbclass feature from Yocto, available since Yocto 4.0. It takes care of setting up everything needed for overlayfs.

Comment: Post the actual code fix and you can accept your own answer (after 48 hrs), gain valuable reputation points, and possibly have other readers upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the overlayfs-etc.bbclass feature from Yocto instead, which is available since Yocto 4.0. Documentation at: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#ref-classes-overlayfs-etc

The bbclass patches the init process in /sbin/init to create the folders at runtime before mounting the overlay. See: https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/files/overlayfs-etc-preinit.sh.in

Adding it to you image is really simple:

Add to your machine.conf:

```
OVERLAYFS_ETC_MOUNT_POINT = "/data_local"
OVERLAYFS_ETC_DEVICE = "/dev/mmcblk0p6"
OVERLAYFS_ETC_FSTYPE = "ext4"
OVERLAYFS_ETC_MOUNT_OPTIONS = "defaults,sync"
```

Add to your image:

```
IMAGE_FEATURES:append = " overlayfs-etc"
```

Of course you must make sure your boot medium has an extra read-write mounted partition already available (in the image flashed to SD card) - in my case mmcblk0p6.

Comment: The wonderful obscurities of embedded systems. How did you stumble on this solution? Thanks for posting it!